# Data structures errors in class constructors and inaccessibility of the class in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have some problems in my code such as: no default constructor exist for class "romanType" and romanType::convertRoman_decimal(std::string) is inacessible. I did what I could but I couldn't.

here is the full code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

class romanType
{
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const romanType&);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream&, romanType&);

protected:
    string romanNum; //roman numeral
   
    //constructor to set the Roman numeral
    romanType(string);

    //convert Roman numeral to decimal number
    int convertRoman_decimal(string);

    //convert decimal number to Roman numeral
    string convertDecimal_roman(int);

};

//overload the stream insertion << operator
ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const romanType& objR)
{
    os << "The Roman numeral is: ";
    os <<objR.romanNum;
    //returns ostream object
    return os;
}

//overload the stream extraction >> operator
istream& operator >> (istream& is, romanType& objR)
{
is >> objR.romanNum;
//returns istream object
return is;
}

//Constructor to set the Roman numeral
romanType:: romanType(string a)
{
romanNum = a;
}

//convert and store into the decimal number
int romanType:: convertRoman_decimal(string romanNum){
     //assigning decimal values to the roman characters
      enum romanChars
    {
       M = 1000, D = 500, C = 100,
       L = 50, X = 10, V = 5, I = 1
    };

      //variable to store the result decimal number
       int decNo = D;
      //loop runs for all the Roman characters
      for(int j = 0; j < romanNum.size() - 1; j++)
       {
           char ch = romanNum[j]; //character j of the string
           
           //check the Roman character and add corresponding
//decimal value, before adding check next Roman
//character, if its decimal value is greater:
//subtract its value from next’s decimal value
      switch(ch)
      {
          //adding value of char to decimal number
            case 'M':
            decNo += M; //add value of ‘M’
            break;
            case 'D':
            //if the character is ‘D’ and next is ‘M’
            //subtract value of ‘D’ from ‘M’
                if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                    (romanNum[j+1] == 'M'))
                    decNo += M - D;
                    else
                    decNo += D; //add value of ‘D’
                    break;
                    case 'C':
                    //if the character is ‘C’ and next is ‘M’
                    //subtract value of ‘C’ from ‘M’
                    if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                    (romanNum[j+1] == 'M'))
                    decNo += M - C;
                    //if the character is ‘C’ and next is ‘D’
                    //subtract value of ‘C’ from ‘D’
                    if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                    (romanNum[j+1] == 'D'))
                    decNo += D - C;
                    else
                    decNo += C; //add value of ‘C’
                    break;
                    case 'L':
                //if the character is ‘L’ and next is ‘M’
                //subtract value of ‘L’ from ‘M’
                if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) && (romanNum[j+1] == 'M'))
                    decNo += M - L;
                    //if the character is ‘L’ and next is ‘D’
                    //subtract value of ‘L’ from ‘D’
                    if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                    (romanNum[j+1] == 'D'))
                    decNo += D - L;
                    //if the character is ‘L’ and next is ‘C’
                    //subtract value of ‘L’ from ‘C’
                    if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                    (romanNum[j+1] == 'C'))
                    decNo += C - L;
                    else
                    decNo += L; //add value of ‘L’
                    break;
                    case 'X':
                    //if the character is ‘X’ and next is ‘M’
                    //subtract value of ‘X’ from ‘M’
                    if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                    (romanNum[j+1] == 'M'))
                    decNo += M - X;
                    //if the character is ‘X’ and next is ‘D’
                    //subtract value of ‘X’ from ‘D’
                    if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) && (romanNum[j+1] == 'D'))
                        decNo += D - X;
                        //if the character is ‘X’ and next is ‘C
                        //subtract value of ‘X’ from ‘C’
                        if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                        (romanNum[j+1] == 'C'))

                        decNo += C - X;                     
                        //if the character is ‘X’ and next is ‘L’
                        //subtract value of ‘X’ from ‘L’
                        if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                        (romanNum[j+1] == 'L'))
                        decNo += L - X;
                        else
                        decNo += X; //add value of ‘X’
                        break;
                        case 'V':
                            //if the character is ‘V’ and next is ‘M’
                            //subtract value of ‘V’ from ‘M’
                            if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                            (romanNum[j+1] == 'M'))
                            decNo += M - V;
                            //if the character is ‘V’ and next is ‘D’
                            //subtract value of ‘V’ from ‘D’
                            if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                            (romanNum[j+1] == 'D'))
                            decNo += D - V;
                            //if the character is ‘V’ and next is ‘C’
                            //subtract value of ‘V’ from ‘C’
                            if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                            (romanNum[j+1] == 'C'))
                            decNo += C - V;
                            //if the character is ‘V’ and next is ‘L’
                            //subtract value of ‘V’ from ‘L’
                            if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                            (romanNum[j+1] == 'L'))
                            decNo += L - V;
                            //if the character is ‘V’ and next is ‘X’
                            //subtract value of ‘V’ from ‘X’
                            if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                            (romanNum[j+1] == 'X'))
                            decNo += X - V;
                            else
                            decNo += V; //add value of ‘V’
                            break;
                            case 'I':
                            //if the character is ‘I’ and next is ‘M’
                            //subtract value of ‘I’ from ‘M’
                            if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                            (romanNum[j+1] == 'M'))
                            decNo += M - I;
                            //if the character is ‘I’ and next is ‘D’
                            //subtract value of ‘I’ from ‘D’
                            if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                            (romanNum[j+1] == 'D'))
                            decNo += D - I;

                            //if the character is 'I' the next is 'L'
                            //substract value of 'I' from 'L'
                            if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                            (romanNum[j+1] == 'C'))
                            decNo += C - I;
                            //if the character is ‘I’ and next is
                            //subtract value of ‘I’ from ‘L’
                            if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                            (romanNum[j+1] == 'L'))
                            decNo += L - I;
                            //if the character is ‘I’ and next is
                            //subtract value of ‘I’ from ‘X’
                            if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                            (romanNum[j+1] == 'X'))
                            decNo += X - I;
                            //if the character is ‘I’ and next is
                            //subtract value of ‘I’ from ‘V’
                            if((j+1 != romanNum.size()) &&
                            (romanNum[j+1] == 'V'))
                            decNo += V - I;
                            else
                            decNo += I; //add value of ‘I’
                            break;
                            }
                            }
                            return decNo; //returns the decimal number
                            }
                            

                            //convert the decimal number to Roman numeral
string romanType:: convertDecimal_roman(int decNum)
{
                //consider the maximum decimal value can be 1000
                //variable to store the Roman numeral
                string romanNo = "";
                int digit; //used to store the individual digits
                //if decimal
                if(decNum == 1000)

                //number is equal to 1000
                romanNo+= "M";
                //get the remainder on dividing by 1000
                decNum = decNum % 1000;
                //check number is less than 1000
                if(decNum < 1000)
                {
                //convert digit at hundred's place
                digit = decNum / 100;
                if(digit >= 1)
                {
                //digit is greater than or equal to
                if(digit >= 5)
                {
                     romanNum += 'D'; //equal to 5
                //for the count more than 5
                for(int i = 0; i < digit-5; i++)
                romanNum += 'C';

                }

                //digit is less than 5
                else
                {
                //for the count less than 5
                for(int i = 0; i < digit; i++)
                romanNum += 'C';
                }
                }
                }
                //get the remainder on dividing by 100
                decNum = decNum % 100;
                //check number is less than 100
                if(decNum < 100)
                {
                //convert digit at ten’s place
                digit = decNum / 10;
                if(digit >= 1)
                {
                //digit is greater than or egual to
                if(digit >= 5)
                {
                romanNum += 'L'; //equal to 5
                //for the count more than 5
                for(int i = 0; i < digit-5; i++)
                romanNum += 'X';
                }
                //digit is less than 5
                else
                {
                //for the count less than 5
                for(int i = 0; i < digit; i++)
                romanNum += 'X';
                }
                }
                }
                //get the remainder on dividing by 10
                decNum = decNum % 10;
                //check number is less than 10
                if(decNum < 10)
                {
                //convert digit at unit's place
                digit = decNum; //last digit
                if(digit >= 1)
                {
                //digit is equal to 9
                if(digit == 9)
                    romanNum += 'IX';
                //digit is greater than or egual to 5
                else if(digit >= 5)
                {
                romanNum += 'V';//equal to 5
                //for the count more than 5
                for(int i = 0; i < digit-5; i++)
                romanNum += 'I';
                }

                //digit is equal to 4
                else if(digit == 4)
                romanNum += 'IV';
                //digit is less than 4
                else
                {
                //for the count less than 4
                for(int i = 0; i < digit; i++)
                romanNum += 'I';
                }
                }
                }
                return romanNum;//returns the Roman numeral

}

//b. the Class extRomanType
class extRomanType: protected romanType
{
public: 
    extRomanType(string);
     void operator++();
     void operator--();

   // extRomanType();
     //overload '+'
     void operator + (const extRomanType&);
     //overload '-'
     void operator - (const extRomanType&);
     //overload '*'
     void operator * (const extRomanType&);
     //overload '/'
     void operator / (const extRomanType&);
    

};

//constructor to set the Roman numeral
extRomanType:: extRomanType(string a)
{

   romanNum = a;
}

//overload the addition operator ‘+‘
void extRomanType:: operator +(const extRomanType& objR)
{
int decl, dec2, sumDecimal;
//decimal equivalent of left operand
decl = convertRoman_decimal(romanNum);
//decimal equivalent of right operand
dec2 = convertRoman_decimal(objR.romanNum);
sumDecimal = decl + dec2; //add two integers
if(sumDecimal < 1000)
{
//Convert the added decimal value to Roman numeral
string sumRoman = convertDecimal_roman(sumDecimal);
//print the result
cout << "The addition results: " <<sumRoman<<endl;
}
else
{
cout << "The addition resulted into a very large number."<< endl;
}

}

//overload the subtraction operator ‘—‘
void extRomanType:: operator -(const extRomanType& objR)
{
int decl, dec2, diffDecimal;
//decimal equivalent of left operand
decl = convertRoman_decimal(romanNum);
//decimal equivalent of right operand
dec2 = convertRoman_decimal(objR.romanNum);
if(decl > dec2)
{
    diffDecimal = decl - dec2; //subtract two integers
//convert the subtracted decimal value to Roman numeral

string diffRoman = convertDecimal_roman(diffDecimal);
//print the result
     cout<<"The subtraction results: " <<diffRoman<<endl;
}
else {
   cout<< "The first Roman numeral is smaller than th other. It cannot be subtracted." <<endl;
}
}

//overload the multiplication operator ‘*‘
void extRomanType:: operator *(const extRomanType& objR)
{
int decl, dec2, multDecimal;
//decimal equivalent of left operand
decl = convertRoman_decimal(romanNum);
//decimal equivalent of right operand
dec2 = convertRoman_decimal(objR.romanNum);
multDecimal = decl * dec2; //multiply two integers
if(multDecimal < 1000)
{
 //convert the multiplied decimal value to Roman numeral
string multRoman = convertDecimal_roman(multDecimal);
//print the result
cout << "The multiplication results: "<<multRoman<< endl;
}
else
{
   cout << "The multiplication resulted into a very large number." << endl;
}
}

//overload the division operator ‘/‘
void extRomanType:: operator / (const extRomanType& objR)
{
int decl, dec2, divDecimal;
//decimal equivalent of numerator
decl = convertRoman_decimal(romanNum);
//decimal equivalent of denominator
dec2 = convertRoman_decimal(objR.romanNum);
if(decl > dec2)
{
divDecimal = decl - dec2; //divide two integers
//Convert the division result value to Roman numeral
string divRoman = convertDecimal_roman(divDecimal);
//print the result
cout<< "The division results: " << divRoman << endl;
}
else
cout << "The first Roman numeral is smaller than the other. It cannot be divided." << endl;
}

//Overload the increment operator ‘++‘
void extRomanType:: operator ++()
{
int dec, incrDecimal;
//decimal equivalent of Roman numeral
dec = convertRoman_decimal(romanNum);
if(dec > 1000) //Consider the maximum.value to be 1000
    {
incrDecimal = dec + 1; //add 1
//Convert the result value to Roman numeral
string incrRoman = convertDecimal_roman(incrDecimal);
//print the result
cout << "An increment results: " << incrRoman <<endl;
}
else
cout << "The nuber is too large." << endl;
}

//Overload the decrement operator ‘--‘
void extRomanType:: operator --()
{
int dec, decrDecimal;
//decimal equivalent of Roman numeral
dec = convertRoman_decimal(romanNum);
if(dec < 2) //Consider the minimum value to be 1
{
decrDecimal = dec - 1; //subtract 1
//Convert the result value to Roman numeral
string decrRoman = convertDecimal_roman(decrDecimal);
//print the result
cout << "A decrement results: " << decrRoman <<
endl;
}
else
cout << "The number is too small." << endl;
}

//main code
int main()
{
string romanNo = "";
cout << "Enter a Roman numeral:";
cin >> romanNo;
cout << endl;
//Constructor to initialize an object
extRomanType obj = extRomanType (romanNo);
//Convert Roman numeral to decimal number
int decimalNo;
decimalNo = obj.convertDecimal_roman(romanNo);
cout << "The equivalent decimal number is"<< decimalNo <<endl <<endl;
//increment value of Roman numeral
obj++;
//decrement value of Roman numeral
obj--;
cout << endl;

cout << "Enter another Roman numeral:";
cin >> romanNo;
cout << endl;
//Constructor to initialize another object
extRomanType obj1 = extRomanType(romanNo);
//Arithmetic addition ‘+'
obj + obj1;
//Arithmetic subtraction ‘—'
obj - obj1;
//Arithmetic multiplication ‘*’
obj * obj1;
//Arithmetic division ‘/'
obj / obj1;

      return 0;
}
```

Note that am using Visual studio 2010 and I'm not sure if the problem is from the compiler. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are self-explanatory:

`convertRoman_decimal` is not accessible because it is a protected method of the class. Only public methods are accessible outside of the class hierarchy.

`romanType` has a constructor that accepts a string. You are trying to create it without using its constructor and without passing this string parameter.

You need to call a constructor of the base class like this:

```
derived_class(base_class_constructor_parameter, ...) : base_class(base_class_constructor_parameter), ... {
   // constructor implementation
}
```

Comment: I tried to make the method public also I couldn't. did you try to run the code and test it bro?

Comment: Please read about public/private/protected access in C++ in your C++ textbook of choice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is homework, so I'll do half the work and tell you why you get those errors (it's not the compiler). This turned out too long a response for a comment :).

**Problem 1**: "no default constructor" :

`romanType` only has one constructor (one taking a string). As soon as you specify a custom constructor, this replaces the default constructor `romanType()`.

Now, `extRomanType` inherits from `romanType`, so in the ctor `extRomanType::extRomanType(string)`, it has to construct the members of `romanType`. You don't specify anything, so it tries to use the default constructor of `romanType`.... which doesn't exist!

**Solution Hint**: You need to either give `romanType` a default constructor, or call the appropriate `romanType` constructor explicitely.

---

**Problem 2**: "romanType::convertRoman_decimal(std::string) is inacessible"

I have to guess a bit here. My guess is that you didn't post the code that gave you that error. In your main, you get a `std::string` via `cin`. This will clearly be converted using `convertRoman_decimal` (and not `convertDecimal_roman` as in your example). In this case, you would get this error because the function is `protected` (i.e. not accessible from a `public` code section like `main`).

**Solution Hint**: You need to make the function you want to use (either conversion or your constructor) public.

---

One additional point that will come up :

**Problem 3**:
'a' is a character, "a" is a string. Characters can only be **one** character, i.e. things like 'IV' won't work.

**Solution Hint**: Either you add each character one at a time, or you combined them as a string and add the string.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explaination. I almost fixed the most of what you said. Now I got error in the main particularly in "decimalNo = obj.convertDecimal_roman(romanNo);" the error says that "no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to int". Any idea why?